# ¿Cómo convertir valores numéricos (obtenidos de un archivo Excel) en fechas?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

**Transfondo:**

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# que usa [Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) para leer información de varias hojas pertenecientes a un archivo de Excel.

El archivo Excel *(llamado Libro1.xlsx)* contiene dos hojas, una de esas hojas posee una columna que muestra valores de tipo fecha:

*Ejemplo:*

[image: Muestra de la columna "Periodo" con datos de tipo fecha]

Sin embargo, al usar Open XML siguiendo el código suministrado en esta [página](https://dotnetthoughts.net/read-excel-as-datatable-using-openxml-and-c/), los resultados visibles en un `GridView` *(cuyo DataSource es un DataTable)*, muestra los valores de la columna "Periodo" en formato numérico:

*Resultado visible en el GridView con columnas autogeneradas:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo convierto estos números en fechas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de consultar en el chat de Stack Overflow en Español, así como continuando con mi búsqueda, encontré esta [respuesta en Stack Overflow *en inglés*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4538321/4092887) en donde indica que el valor numérico es un valor en formato OLE Automation.

Entonces, para convertir el valor numérico en formato OLE Automation a DateTime, se usa el método [`FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx):

Ejemplo:

```
double valorOLE = 42736;
DateTime fecha_inicio_anio_actual = DateTime.FromOADate(valorOLE);
// Resultado: 01/01/2017 00:00:00
```

Para convertir una variable de tipo DateTime a OLE Automation, se usa el método [`ToOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx):

Ejemplo:

```
DateTime fecha_inicio_anio_actual = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
// Resultado: 01/01/2017 00:00:00
double valorOLE = fecha_inicio_anio_actual.ToOADate();
// Resultado: 42736
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas convertir los números obtenidos en una fecha utilizando `DateTime.FromOADate(value);`

Prueba con el siguiente código en el método `GetCellValue`:

```
private static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
{
    SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
    string value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    { //compara si es un string
        return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
    }
    else
    { //si es un numero o fecha
        DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(value);            
        string val = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return val;
    }
}
```

Necesitas determinar dentro si es un número simple o en este caso si es una fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que al evaluar  `if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)` entra tu tipo de datos Fecha y lo parsean.
Deberías hacer otra condición if antes de este if en donde caches el tipo Date y lo devuelvas como tal y al if siguiente(la que parsea a int) le pones un else if